# How can I get the uploaded file path of a contact form in drupal 8

Tags: 8, forms, hooks, files, emails

I'm using the `hook_mail_alter()` to create a custom email for contact forms.
I was able to get the fields labels and values and use a twig template to send the email. Most of it is working just fine, but my problem is when I use file fields on the contact form. I want to be able to show the path of the uploaded files. When I use the default drupal email, it shows the paths at the end of the file. I want to do the same thing at my custom email. Can anyone tell me how to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get the file entity directly from the field and check if the field is not empty before applying any methods on the file object:

```
/** @var \Drupal\contact\Entity\Message $contactMessage */
$contactMessage = $message['params']['contact_message'];
$file = $contactMessage->field_file->entity;
if (!empty($file)) {
  $fileInfo[] = [
    'value' => $file->getFilename(),
    'url' => $file->url(),
  ];
}
```

Comment: Thanks! That is better than what I was doing. I was surprised that using `->getEntity()` gets the Message Entity and `->entity` gets the File Entity.

Answer (score 1):

I solved my question by getting the file from the fileId.

```
/** @var \Drupal\contact\Entity\Message $contactMessage */
$contactMessage = $message['params']['contact_message'];
$fileId = $contactMessage->get('field_file')->getValue()[0]['target_id'];
$file = \Drupal\file\Entity\File::load($fileId);
$fileInfo[] = [
    'value' => $file->getFilename(),
    'url' => $file->url(),
];
```